# how to get the first touch point and the second touch point on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When i touch on screen, this touch point is the first point and when moving to another location is second touch point. And moving to another location is third. I want get  co-ordinate of these point? Please give me any idea.

Comment: Are you using xaml, DirectX? Building an app, a game?

Comment: I build an application.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is a good place to start.